# How to trigger change of input field in OPA5 tests

Tags: jquery, automated-tests, sapui5, qunit

I have a SAPUI5 application where a controller reacts to both the [`livechange`](https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/#docs/api/symbols/sap.m.Input.html#event:liveChange) and [`change`](https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/#docs/api/symbols/sap.m.InputBase.html#event:change) events of `sap.m.Input`.

How do I trigger these events in OPA5 tests? Among the demo apps, I couldn't find any example.

So far, my code looks like this, employing [jQuery.change](http://api.jquery.com/change/):

```
return this.waitFor({
    id: "id_of_input_control",
    success: function (control) {
        control.$().children("input")
            .focus()
            .val("test")
            .change()
            .blur();
    },
    errorMessage: "Failed to find PLB input field"
});
```

This does trigger the `change`, but not the `livechange` event.

Any idea how to trigger both in the right order?

Answer (score 1):

It would be simpler to use 'Actions' like this:

```
When.waitFor({
    id: "myInput",
    // If you want you can provide multiple actions
    actions: new EnterText({ text: "Hello " }))
});
```

[OPA5 Actions](https://openui5.hana.ondemand.com/#docs/guide/8615a0b9088645ae936dbb8bbce5d01d.html)

Answer (score 0):

I came up with the following helper function:

```
/**
 * 
 * @param {sap.ui.core.Control} oControl    - The UI5 control on which to enter input, usually sap.m.Input
 * @param {string}              sValue      - The text to set
 * @param {boolean}             [bDontBlur] - Avoid defocusing the control after text entry, which may be
 *                                            useful in non-modal popovers. Defaults to false.
 */
function processInputOnControl(oControl, sValue, bDontBlur) {
    oControl = oControl[0] || oControl;
    oControl = oControl.$().children("input");
    oControl.focus()
        .val(sValue)
        .trigger("input")
        .change();

    if (!bDontBlur) { // Blur event may close non-modal popovers, so it is optional
        oControl.blur();
    }
}
```

Comment: Manual triggering of events is a never ending game, controls change what even handlers they hook. The best way is to use the Press/EnterText events that are covered by extensive unit test and very they continue to work on every ui5 commit.